# How to add an id in Kivy's .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm struggling to come up with a simple example for using IDs. Later I want to use the IDs to change parameters, for instance to change the text in a label or a button. So how do I get started? I can't find  simple example for using IDs.

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class TestApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0

Button:
    text: 'this button \n is the root'
    color: .8, .9, 0, 1
    font_size: 32

    Label: 
        text: 'This is a label'
        color: .9, 0, .5, .5
```

In this case I would like to use an ID for the label and be able to change the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some info about the kv language [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code).
You need to use [kivy properties](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#binding-to-properties-of-properties) for that.

here is an example on how you can change the label text when you press the button:
python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class GridScreen(GridLayout):
    label = ObjectProperty() #accessing the label in python
    def btnpress(self):
        self.label.text = 'btn pressed' #changing the label text when button is pressed

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<GridScreen>:
    label: label #referencing the label
    rows: 2
    Button:
        text: 'this button \n is the root'
        color: .8, .9, 0, 1
        font_size: 32
        on_press: root.btnpress() #calling the method 

    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'This is a label'
        color: .9, 0, .5, .5
```